# Why is my fetched data that return as an array keep getting the error "Objects are not valid as a React child"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

App.tsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import UserInput from "./components/userInput";
import { ResultRow } from "./components/ResultRow";

// type TCachedValues = {
//   [keys: string]: object | void
// };

function App() {
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");
  const [cachedResults, setCachedResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCachedResults = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(
          "https://ambeigj4hx.us.aircode.run/cachedValues"
        );
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Response("Non 200 HTTP Status", res);
        }
        const data = await res.json();
        setCachedResults(data)
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
      } catch (err: any) {
        switch (err.status) {
          case 400:
            break;
          case 401:
            break;
          case 404:
            break;
          case 500:
            break;
        }
        console.log(err);
      }
      
      return () => {};
    }

    fetchCachedResults();
    
  }, []);
  
  console.log(cachedResults) 
  console.log(typeof cachedResults)

  return (
    <>
      <div className="h-screen text-white bg-gradient-radial from-[#2e4363] via-[#1e3258] to-[#111c33]">
        <main className="mx-auto px-4 py-8 max-w-2xl">
          <h1 className="font-bold text-6xl text-center">NFL STAT TRACKER</h1>
          <div className="flex justify-center mt-8">
            <UserInput
              className=""
              value={userInput}
              onChange={(e) => setUserInput(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mt-8">
            <ResultRow results={cachedResults} userInput={userInput} />
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Not sure how to display the data that I was able to fetch... feels demoralizing and need assistance and a good explanation as to how to approach this maybe a bit more elegantly. The data fetched is in an array but when I console.log it's typeof, it reads as an object even after setting it to a state with an empty array.

The project is a NFL Stat tracker for the latest data I was able to fetch for people to look up stats easier for building parlays lol, and i want the user to be able to search any offensive player listed within the data

https://github.com/joequint22/nfl-stats

Comment: If you want to  display data in parlays; you should use the bootstrap card and  make it in your way
All the array returns ***type of always an Object*** .

Answer (score 0):

not sure which format would you prefer for your data, but here is one of the options:

1.transform the data you receive before saving it

```
setCachedResults(transformData(data))
```

with

```
const transformData = (data) => {
  const [value] = data;
  const teamNames = Object.keys(value).filter(key => !['createdAt', 'updatedAt', '_id'].includes(key));
  return teamNames?.map(name => [name, data[name]]);
}
```

and then in the ResultsRow component change the rendering to:

```
    {results.map(([teamName, data], key) => {
       return (
        <div key={key}>
            <h1>${teamName}</h1>
        </div>
       )
    })}
```

Comment: so basically your problem is with the format of data you receive: if you look it up in Network tab (F12), you'll see that it is 1 object inside an array, so what I did is took that object and turned into an array [teamName, teamData].
Another option would be to
return teamNames?.map(name => ({...data[name], teamName: name});